# Is my interior door LH or RH?

Tags: doors

Have just read your 2010 posts regarding whether an interior door is LH or RH.  Using the "hand that plus the door toward you" guideline, I get the opposite of what I get when using the hinge/jamb guideline. I do in fact have 3 interior doors that pull toward me using right hand but using the jamb guideline, they are LH. I would call these outswing as they do not swing  IN to the area they are closing. I have another door into a small bath I would call inswing RH using the jamb guideline but LH using the left hand to pull towards me. I'm starting to like the idea to take a drawing with me...

Answer (score 2):

Stand in front of the door.

- If the handle moves away from you and to the left, it's left handed.
- If  the handle moves toward you and to the right, it's left handed.
- If the handle moves away from you and to the right, it's right handed.
- If the handle moves toward you and to the left, it's right handed.

Basically, if it opens away from you, it's whichever way it opens to. If it opens toward you, it's the opposite of whichever way it opens.

Answer (score 2):

How about this,

when you **pull** the door open, where is the knob.

on the left, it's a left
on the right, it's a right

Comment: This is a LOT easier to remember!